# Displaying page with WEBrick from Nitrous?

Tags: ruby, webrick, nitrousio

I'm trying to develop a very simple rails app from Nitrous.
When I type in 'rails s' to pull up the app on local server, I get the following:

```
 => Booting WEBrick                                                                                                                                                                            
 => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000                                                                                                                   
 => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options                                                                                                                                             
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server                                                                                                                                                                  
 Exiting 

 /home/action/workspace/todo-app/config/routes.rb:60:in `<top (required)>':                               undefined method `root' for main:Object (NoMethodError)                                                            
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'                                                                           
    from /home/action/.gem/ruby/2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
```

This is followed by a long list of lines which begin with 'from'
Any suggestions as to what I might be missing?
I am very knew to this, and my knowledge is quite limited.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Looks like there is an error in your `routes` file, specifically the `root` method being called outside the `Rails.application.routes.draw` block, but it's hard to verify without seeing the code. Rails is telling you the exact line and file where it thinks the error is so you should look there.

Comment: One other thing to note is that you'll want to run your Rails app on 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost when using Nitrous. Try running the command `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` after fixing your routing error @ptd mentioned.